# Launching a new thread during static initialization

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mingw

I have a DLL that needs to spawn a new thread when it is loaded. My current approach is something like this:

```
struct Dummy {Dummy() {} };
Dummy obj;

Dummy::Dummy()
{
     std::thread t([]() {std::cout<<"Helloworld\n"; });
     assert( t.joinable() );
     t.join();
}
```

Unfortunately, this code hangs forever at the `t.join()` line, and it does not print anything. The main application loads the dll with `LoadLibrary`.

I am using gcc 4.8 from Mingw.

Comment: Look at this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx `Because DLL notifications are serialized, entry-point functions should not attempt to communicate with other threads or processes. Deadlocks may occur as a result.` `If your DLL is linked with the C run-time library (CRT), the entry point provided by the CRT calls the constructors and destructors for global and static C++ objects. Therefore, these restrictions for DllMain also apply to constructors and destructors and any code that is called from them.`

Comment: So, creating a thread in DllMain or global object constructor is a bad thing. Joining a thread is catastrophic.